# Automatically add a set .gitignore file to a New Project folder location when creating a New Project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to have a certain .gitignore file created in the directory of a New Project when I create it in IntelliJ. Is there a way to set this up to automatically happen?

[image: Screenshot of where the file would be. "I think"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use project templates for that. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/saving-project-as-template.html